# Prohorov metric is unchanged if condition required only for closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\pi$ be the Prohorov distance between elements $P$ and $Q$ of the space of probability measures on the Borel $\sigma-$field of a metric space $S$, i.e. the infimum of those positive $\epsilon$ for which the two inequalities 
$$PA \le QA^\epsilon + \epsilon, \; QA \le PA^\epsilon + \epsilon$$ hold for all Borel sets $A$.

I've came across the notion that this definition remains unchanged if we replace Borel sets for closed sets $A$. How can we prove this equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be any Borel set. Then there exists a sequence of closed sets $C_n$ such that $C_n \subset A$ and $P(C_n) \to P(C)$. [Theorem 1.1 in Billgsley's Convergence of Probability Measures]. So $P(C_n) \leq Q((C_n)^{\epsilon}) +\epsilon$ implies $P(C_n) \leq Q((A)^{\epsilon}) +\epsilon$ and letting $n \to \infty$ we get $P(A) \leq Q((A)^{\epsilon}) +\epsilon$.  The second inequality is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The validity of the assertion can be explained by the following observations:

- For any set $A\subset X$, $A^\varepsilon = (\overline{A})^\varepsilon$. This follows from the simple identity
  $$ d(x,A)=d(x,\overline{A})$$
- If for some $\varepsilon>0$, $P(F)<Q(F^\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$ holds for any closed set $F$, then for a Borel set $A$,
  $$P(A)\leq P(\overline{A})\leq Q\big((\overline{A})^\varepsilon\big)+\varepsilon=Q(A^\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$$